# how to do weblogic authentication for a web application

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-soa

I want to know how to perform aunthentication on weblogic server for any web application?

I am a newbie to SOA so I searched the web & found something about **security realms**.

But I dont know much about it.
so I want to know if I can aunthenticate my weblogic server by using java code or not?

I am thinking of writing a java program to allow access to weblogic.
but not sure how to do it.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what direction you want to go, but assuming you're talking about developing Composites in SOA Suite and wanting to secure them, there's a whole section on that:

[Securing SOA Suite 12c](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/soasuite/soasuite-secure.htm)

If you meant something else, you'll have to elaborate what you're trying to do and why you need it.  I don't see you needing to write a java application to access WebLogic, as there are a lot of pre-built roles in a WebLogic environment to give you access to different aspects of it.

[Middleware Documentation Hub](http://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/)

[Securing WebLogic Server 12c](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/wls-secure.htm)